# Запрос выбирает только одну запись

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос:

```
(SELECT `Feed`.*,`Users`.UID,`Users`.Name
 FROM `Feed`,`Users` 
WHERE `Feed`.ID > '22' 
AND ((`AccessKey` = '' or `AccessKey` = 'key123') 
AND (`Feed`.UserCreate = `Users`.UID))) LIMIT 0,10
```

есть 2 пользователя, ID 1 и 2. При таком запросе, результат все 10 записей только одного пользователя, то есть с ID = 1. 
А мне нужно что бы просто присоединяло к таблице 2 столбика с именем и ИД пользователя добавившего данную запись.

Как же не знать про JOIN-ны и UNION, но!, по моему(по крайней мере я не нашел как это сделать) там нельзя ограничить столбцы, то есть в таблице которую клею сбоку, выводит и логин и пароль пользователя. что неуместно.

И да, поменять местами таблицы Feed и Users не могу, потому что, много условий именно к Feed, а Users так, только 1 выборка по ID

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема была очевидная, забыл добавить ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

1. нет. ваш запрос выбирает 10 записей, среди которых могут быть как записи от юзера с id=1, так и с 2, или с 1000. hint: limit без order by пользы не имеет.
2. join у вас и так есть, только она называется "старый" join, когда связь указывается в выражении where. union тут вообще не к месту. поля, в результате выборки не зависят от join'а или union'а, это тоже тут ни при чем.
3. от перестановки сомножителей произведение не меняется.

приведите пример ваших данных и что вы хотите получить в результате. к таблице 2 вы уже добавили ваши два столбика.

Comment: Как видите, пропускает ID = 24,25,26 ... У который UserCreate = 2 а не 1